# Subpackage for custom events in Java

Tags: java, events, listener, package

Lets assume I have got the four classes divided into two packages:

[image: Cyclical dependency between packages]

I created packages `myapp.engine` and `myapp.engine.events` for its event-handling stuff. As you can see, this creates cyclic dependecy between packages.

How to avoid this? 
In other words: where is the best place to keep event-related classes?

Comment: Why would the event or the listener need to depend on the engine package?

Comment: are you worried it'll get messages not meant to and then it'll do things its not meant to?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: For example, event may contain reference to some class from this package, which is used in SomeClass. Then listeners make use of this class.

Comment: That sounds like more information which should go into the question. A *complete* example showing all the classes involved would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: It seems that the bidirectional dependency only exists because a SomeClassEvent uses SomeClassStuff. As this is obviously part of the event's API, the class SomeClassStuff should also go into the event package. Then you have a clear and cohesive package.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Let's assume for example, that I've got some Lexer (SomeClass) which traverses reads file and fires SymbolParsed (SomeClassEvent) event each time it parses some Symbol (SomeClassStuff). Is in this case Symbol part of event's API or rather Lexer's?

Comment: As far as I can see, these are information that you did not put into your original question. Any answer and comment can only refer to the _known_ information. If your question is much more complicated, you should tell it in your question. In fact, if `SomeClassStuff` does not belong to the event package, then `SomeClassEvent` should not depend on it. Make the field `_retrievedStuff` be of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. Now it's time for summary. I have following proposed solutions:

### **Make `_retrievedStuff` be of type `Object`**

Mentioned by [Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose). It will break the cycle, but then we will lose information about type of `_retrievedStuff`.

### **Move `SomeClassStuff` to event package**

Mentioned again by [Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose). This solution will work too, but only if `SomeClassStuff` doesn't depend on any of myapp.engine class. Otherwise, cyclical depndency will not disappear.

In my case this won't work, since `SomeClassStuff` is heavily dependent on myapp.engine package. So, I had to choose the third option, which is...

### **Extract event-specific class into event package**

I created class in myapp.engine.events package called `EventStuff` which contains stuff necessary for event handling and **is not dependent** on any class from myapp.engine. Any data and logic from `SomeClassStuff` which was previously required during event handling,  now will be in `EventStuff`.

Then, `SomeClassEvent` will depend only on this class and nothing more. 
Here is class diagram after applying solution:

[image: refactored solution]

Voilà! Simple, but works.